# To find Linear transformation by using Transpose of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Using linear transformation $T:V \to W$ ,we can induce transpose of a linear transformation $T':W' \to V'$ by using linear functional on W. But how can we induce linear transformation $T:V \to W$ by using transpose of linear transformation $T':W' \to V'$? Actually the original question was to find an isomorphism between L(V,W) and L(W',V').I define isomorphism $\alpha:T \to T^{t}$ but got my doubt while showing onto part.

Comment: How do you define transpose?

Comment: $(T^{t}g)=(gT)$

Comment: There is a canonical injection $V \to V’’$, which is an isomorphism if $V$ has finite dimension. By using this isomorphisms, you can show that $T’’$ looks a lot like $T$.

Comment: But I still didn't get how $T^{t}:W'\to V'$ is uniquely attached to $T:V\to W$.